# zookeeper 3.6.2 c client compile failed

Tags: c, apache-zookeeper

I downloaded the 3.6.2 source tarball (apache-zookeeper-3.6.2.tar.gz, sha512sum: 16994067d460a1b6af6a71f3458c64ee32629e876a1ff6646d57be62f1a5adab57462af84074ecaded4186dd3fde035ee24cd9d578b8e5044073eb05f4ab9c3e) from apache zookeeper website. Tried to compile its C client in a debian 10 OS.

In dir zookeeper-client/zookeeper-client-c, I ran "autoreconf -if" and "./configure --enable-debug".  configure complained about "configure: error: jute files are missing! Please run "ant compile_jute" while in the zookeeper top level directory."

But then tried to run "ant compile_jute" at the top dir. complained about "Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!".  Did some search and tried "mvn -pl zookeeper-jute compile" at the top dir. But still have some error. Can anyone know how to solve the issue? Thanks,

```
xing@debian10-dev ~/d/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2> mvn -pl zookeeper-jute compile
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper-jute >-----------------
[INFO] Building Apache ZooKeeper - Jute 3.6.2
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven-version) @ zookeeper-jute ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mavanagaiata:0.9.4:commit (find-current-git-revision) @ zookeeper-jute ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.299 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-20T23:07:23-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.koraktor:mavanagaiata:0.9.4:commit (find-current-git-revision) on project zookeeper-jute: Unable to read Git commit information: Commit "24e9d01f1321d22f1eef2a3fc0f1b3d68f68d12c" could not be loaded. Short read of block. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**Updated on 3/21**:
The instructions coming with README (run "ant compile_jute" at top level dir and then "autoreconf -if; ./configure --enable-debug" in dir zookeeper-client/zookeeper-client-c) seem to work for version **3.5.9**. I have switched to use that version while waiting for them to update the README for 3.6.2.